# In Diplomacy, can a fleet in a coastal province be used to convoy?

Tags: diplomacy

The situation I had in mind was that in Spring, 1901 Italy orders army, Venice to Albania. The Austrian Fleet Trieste does a convoy, since the fleet in the Trieste coastal region is adjacent to both the other two coastal regions. (This would be a Lepanto opening.)

Another player argues that this is not possible. His [reasoning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZyBnL7vs4U&lc=UgwyowWDdyjGzqXIAPl4AaABAg.9LDxd8prz9b9LE3E8vQhVo) is "the convoy is only possible if the fleet vacates Trieste and moves into Adriatic Sea."

According to [Diplomacy Wiki](https://diplomacy.fandom.com/wiki/Convoy), "A fleet can convoy an army that is adjacent to it into another land space that is adjacent to the fleet."

Who is right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fleets in coastal provinces cannot convoy.  To convoy, you have to be in the open water.  From the rules (emphasis mine):

> Convoying an Army Across One Water Province
>
> A Fleet in a **water province (not a coastal province)** can convoy an
> Army from any coastal province adjacent to that water province to
> any other coastal province adjacent to that water province.

> Convoying an Army Across Several Water Provinces
>
> If Fleets occupy **adjacent water provinces**, an Army can be convoyed
> through all these water provinces on one turn, landing in a coastal
> province adjacent to the final Fleet in the chain

Thus, in the situation you describe, a fleet in Trieste cannot convoy; it would need to be in the Adriatic Sea.